# Using the PHP ternary operator to return a specific value

Tags: php, operator-keyword, ternary

I googled this and browsed stack overflow already. I am trying to shorten my code and I have this working method below I want to rewrite in ternary style. Can someone tell me if this is possible and if so what im doing wrong. Thanks.

```
public function __get($field){ //refactor this using ternary method
    if($field == 'user_id'){
        return $this->uid;
    } else {
        return $this->fields[$field];
    }
}
```

I started with this:

```
($field == 'user_id') return $this->uid : return $this->fields[$field];
```

and it gives me a unexpected return error.

I tried using another stack overflow solution that listed the return before the values and that didnt work.

```
return $field == 'user_id' ? $this->uid : $this->fields[$field];
```

This gives me some other error about unexpected public, like my method isnt closing correctly.

Comment: your last code snippet is okay. your error message sounds like you are doing something else wrong

Comment: The latter is definitely the right way; perhaps you could share the exact error message.

Comment: Can you post the exact error you get?

Comment: btw, the unexpected return error is likely due to the missing `?`

Comment: Well spotted @AndreasHenning!

Comment: http://codepad.viper-7.com/ObRDWo

Comment: And again, http://codepad.viper-7.com/tbNnb0

Comment: could you post the complete code of the method? as of now, I'd guess your number of closing curly brackets could be wrong.

Comment: I think we've established that this works :)

Comment: The first example fails not only because of the missing `?`, but because `return (anything)` is not an expression.  If it were, wackiness like `$x = return 3;` would be legal.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess it's something like this; you refactored your code to this:

```
public function __get($field){ //refactor this using ternary method
        return $field == 'user_id' ? $this->uid : $this->fields[$field];
    }
}

public function otherfunction() { /* ... */ }
```

The braces don't match and therefore it closes the class definition and the next parser error is `'unexpected public'` :)

Comment: very likely. I just had the same thought :)